# Creating Android application with Fragments and without support libraries

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am creating an application with `android:minSdkVersion="14"` so I want to avoid support libraries for backward compatibility. 
But [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) requires support libraries for Fragments.

Is it possible to create Android application without support libraries and with Fragments? Please tell me How?

**UPD: fixed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`, use `getFragmentManager()` in the Activity (not `FragmentActivity`, `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`. Use the default `Fragment` class instead of one from the support packages.

The rest is almost the same, since they made the support APIs based on the higher default ones, so transition would be easy when we don't have to use the support packages anymore.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I just have found that my Fragment extends Fragment from support library and fix it. Now it works.  I have no idea why people use support libraries for now. Probably for compatibility with third parties which rely on support libraries (Android Facebook SDK 4.x for example).

Comment: AppCompat is also dependent on it. And without AppCompat you can't have a material theme on older Android versions. Anyways, feel free to mark it as an accepted answer if it has answered your question.